# writing equations side by side

Tags: spacing, formatting, equations

what I want to do is I want to solve my system on the same line. I've solve for x but I also want the part where I solve for y on the right side of the system that I just solved for. Is there a way to get them side by side?

```
     \documentclass[10pt]{article}
     \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
     \usepackage{array}
     \usepackage{booktabs}
     \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

     \begin{document}

     Solve the system.
     \begin{align*}
     6x-5y &= 11 && && & \\
     7x+5y &= 2
     \end{align*}

     \begin{equation}
     \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
     \begin{array}{@{}r@{}>{{}}l@{}}
     6x\; {\cancel{-\;5y}} &= 11 \\
     7x\; {\cancel{+\;5y}} &= 2  \\
     \midrule
     13x &= 13  \\
     x &= 1
     \end{array}
     \end{equation}


     \begin{flalign*}
     \text{Substitute $x=1$ into one of equations to find $y$:} \ \ 6(1)-5y &=11 \\
      6-5y &=11 \\
     -5y &=5 \\
     y &= -1
     \end{flalign*}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

 \begin{document}
 \noindent
 \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
 Solve the following system:
 \begin{align*}
 6x-5y &= 11 \\
 7x+5y &= 2
 \end{align*}
 \end{minipage}

 \bigskip\noindent
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
 Begin by adding the two equations to find $x$:
 \begin{equation*}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
 \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
 \begin{array}{r@{}>{{}}l}
 6x\; {\cancel{{}-5y}} &= 11 \\
 7x\; {\cancel{{}+5y}} &= 2  \\
 \midrule
 13x &= 13  \\
 x &= 1
 \end{array}
 \end{equation*}
 \end{minipage}
 \hspace{\fill} % maximize space between the minipages
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
 Then, substitute $x=1$ into one of the equations to find $y$:
 \begin{align*}
 6(1)-5y &=11 \\
  6-5y &=11 \\
 -5y &=5 \\
 y &= -1
 \end{align*}
 \end{minipage}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

How about this: two `aligned` environments and an `\eqparbox` in between, nested in `flalign`. Eqparbox allows to have a `\parbox` of width the longest line width of the paragraph:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{array, eqparbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\begin{document}

Solve the system.
\begin{align*}
6x-5y &= 11 && && & \\
7x+5y &= 2
\end{align*}

\begin{flalign}
& \begin{aligned}
6x {\cancel{{}- 5y}} &= 11 \\
7x {\cancel{{}+ 5y}} &= 2 \\
\midrule
13x &= 13 \\
x &= 1
\end{aligned}
& & \eqparbox[b]{Expl}{Substitute $x=1$ into \\ one of equations to find $y$:\\}
& &\begin{aligned}
7(1) + 5y & = 2\\
  7 + 5y & =2 \\
 5y &= -5 \\
 y &= -1
\end{aligned}\qquad \end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This option is really good as well. Thank you very much :).